# Spring AOP: Getting return types in after-returning method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I was trying to implement `after-returning` in Spring AOP and the basic implementation works fine:

```
public void afterExecution(JoinPoint jp){
    System.out.println("Returning");
    System.out.println("Returning from: " + jp.toString());
            // How to get the return type object here?
}
```

How to get the return type object in the above method?

This is what I added in the context xml file:

```
<aop:pointcut id="emplRet" expression="execution(java.lang.String com.model.Employee.get*())"/>
    <aop:aspect ref="aspect">
        <aop:after-returning pointcut-ref="emplRet" method="afterExecution"/>
    </aop:aspect>
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify

```
returning="retVal"
```

in your pointcut expression and add a parameter to your method. You would have to reference the bound value `retVal` in your `after-returning` advice.

[Spring AOP documentation.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to change the returning value? Suppose the return value is `1` and I want to return `Male` then is it possible to change the value from `1` to `Male` in the `after-returning` method?

Comment: @user No, you can't. The returned value is stored, the advice is invoked, and then that stored value is returned to the caller. You would need to use an around advice for that. (Be careful with the types though.)

Answer (score 0):

Let us understand this through an example:

I have a class:
[image]

For this getter method ie getList, I want to get returnType in my Aspect Class.

I can access the returnType using @AfterReturning annotation's **returning** parameter.

For example :
[image]

Output from the method is like :
[image]

Hope it clarifies.